# Where to get daily news about new Ubuntu Phone apps?

Tags: software-center, ubuntu-touch

With the release of the Ubuntu phone, the apps environment is going to grow  quite a bit. Is there any resource that offers daily updates about new released apps, scopes etc. in the Ubuntu store?

Answer (score 3):

Not officially from Canonical, but this RSS feed is working really well for me: http://hogsmeade.lieberbiber.de/appstorediff.xml

Here's the script that generates the RSS feed from the Store API, in case you want to host the feed yourself: https://github.com/Sturmflut/ubuntustorediff

Comment: +1 very good solution, to check daily for new apps.

Answer (score 2):

This RSS make it for me: http://feeds.feedburner.com/UbuntuTouchNewApps
It's an unofficial store though.

http://feeds.feedburner.com/UbuntuTouchNewApps

Answer (score 1):

1. You can have a look at [the appstore](https://appstore.bhdouglass.com/apps) from time to time. In the database, you can sort by newest.
2. You may want to look at a [Google Plus Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/111350780270925540549). There are posts about developers questions which may not be that interesting. Howeverm when a new high quality app/update enters the store its usually posted there.